# 1136: Incorrect number of arguments. Expected 0.‎ AS3 Flash Cs4 (Round 2)

Tags: flash, actionscript-3, actionscript

(I have asked this before but I dont think I was direct enough with my question and therefore it did not get resolved so here goes again!)

I am working through a book called *Foundation Actionscript 3.0 Animation, making things move*.

I am now on Chapter 9 - *Collision Detection*. On two lines of my code I get the 1135 error, letting me know that I have an incorrect number of arguments. I have highlighted the two areas in which this occurs with asterisks:

```
package 
{ 
import flash.display.Sprite; 
import flash.events.Event; 
public class Bubbles extends Sprite 
{ 
private var balls:Array; 
private var numBalls:Number = 10; 
private var centerBall:Ball; 
private var bounce:Number = -1; 

private var spring:Number = 0.2; 
public function Bubbles() 
{ 
init(); 
} 
private function init():void 
{ 
balls = new Array(); 
***centerBall = new Ball(100, 0xcccccc);*** 
addChild(centerBall); 
centerBall.x = stage.stageWidth / 2; 
centerBall.y = stage.stageHeight / 2; 
for(var i:uint = 0; i < numBalls; i++) 
{ 
***var ball:Ball = new Ball(Math.random() * 
40 + 5, 
Math.random() * 0xffffff);*** 
ball.x = Math.random() * stage.stageWidth; 
ball.y = Math.random() * stage.stageHeight; 
ball.vx = Math.random() * 6 - 3; 
ball.vy = Math.random() * 6 - 3; 
addChild(ball); 
balls.push(ball); 
} 
addEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME, onEnterFrame); 
} 
private function onEnterFrame(event:Event):void 
{ 
for(var i:uint = 0; i < numBalls; i++) 
{ 
var ball:Ball = balls[i]; 
move(ball); 
var dx:Number = ball.x - centerBall.x; 
var dy:Number = ball.y - centerBall.y; 
var dist:Number = Math.sqrt(dx * dx + dy * dy); 
var minDist:Number = ball.radius + centerBall.radius; 
if(dist < minDist) 
{ 
var angle:Number = Math.atan2(dy, dx); 
var tx:Number = centerBall.x + 
Math.cos(angle) * minDist; 
var ty:Number = centerBall.y + 
Math.sin(angle) * minDist; 
ball.vx += (tx - ball.x) * spring; 
ball.vy += (ty - ball.y) * spring; 
} 
} 
} 
private function move(ball:Ball):void
{ 
ball.x += ball.vx; 
ball.y += ball.vy; 
if(ball.x + ball.radius > stage.stageWidth) 
{ 
ball.x = stage.stageWidth - ball.radius; 
ball.vx *= bounce; 
} 
else if(ball.x - ball.radius < 0) 
{ 
ball.x = ball.radius; 
ball.vx *= bounce; 
} 
if(ball.y + ball.radius > stage.stageHeight) 
{ 
ball.y = stage.stageHeight - ball.radius; 
ball.vy *= bounce; 
} 
else if(ball.y - ball.radius < 0) 
{ 
ball.y = ball.radius; 
ball.vy *= bounce; 
} 
} 
} 
}
```

I think this is due to the non-existance of a `Ball.as`, when reading the tutorial I assumed it meant that I had to create a movie clip of a ball on stage and then export it for actionscript with the class name being Ball, however when flicking back through the book I saw that a `Ball.as` already existed, stating that I may need to use this again later on in the book, this read:

```
package 
{ 
import flash.display.Sprite; 
public class Ball extends Sprite 
{ 
private var radius:Number; 
private var color:uint; 
public var vx:Number=0; 
public var vy:Number=0; 
public function Ball(radius:Number=40, color:uint=0xff0000) 
{ 
this.radius=radius; 
this.color=color; init(); 
} 
public function init():void 
{
 graphics.beginFill(color); 
graphics.drawCircle(0, 0, radius); 
graphics.endFill();
 }
 }
 }
```

This managed to stop all the errors appearing however, it did not transmit any of the effects from `Bubbles.as` it just braught a Red Ball on the center of the stage. How would I alter this code in order to work in favour of Bubbles.as?

Please Help! Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It ran fine for me, however I needed to make some adjustments to the code you've provided - I noticed that from your Bubbles class you are trying to access Ball's properties that are set as private (radius, color), so either set them public or create the proper getter/setter methods for that matter.

```
public var radius:Number;
public var color:uint;
```

or if you want to use getter/setter functions

```
private var _radius:Number;
private var _color:uint;

public function get radius():Number
{
   return _radius;
}
public function set radius(val:Number):void
{
   _radius = val;
}

public function get color():uint
{
   return _color;
}
public function set color(val:uint):void
{
   _color= val;
}
```

After that change was made, I just set Bubbles as my FLA document root, and bam!

Comment: oh my falomir you really helped me out thank you so much, is it rude if i ask you one last question? You got it working right? so you know what it looks like is there anyway i could make the static ball in the center follow the mouse movement???